# Ionic list last child border styles behavior

Tags: ionic-framework

Using the following markup:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label></ion-label>
    <ion-input></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label></ion-label>
    <ion-input></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

It adds weird `:last-child` styling for the borders, which is even found in the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#stacked-labels):

[image]

Notice how the password's border doesn't align like the username field's. Is there a reason for this behavior? Is there a way to change it [easily] without having to go through a ton of styles, i.e. selectors like this:

```
.item-input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(.input-has-focus):not(.item-input-has-focus):last-child
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it is something they have done intentionally or accidentally, but to overcome this quickly whilst I have a ticket outstanding with them I did the following

I created a new ion item at the bottom of the list to act as the last item, then just set the display none on it.

This fixes the border issue for me as it is then applied to the hidden last ion item.

Ticket - https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/5283